# Transform user name before displaying

Tags: users, user-meta, wp-user-query

Users are created whith name in upper case on my site, but some admin want to display it in lower case.
I had a custom field in user profile to identified those admin, but I don't know what hook I can use to change last_name case before it's displaying.

I tried "pre_user_query" in order to change SQL request width LOWER(last_name) but meta hare not directly accessible.

Is someone has an idea ?

Answer (score 0):

Hard to say without seeing any code as to how you are building it out but one suggestion would be to update the field on submit prior to running your register_new_user function.

PHP strtolower() Function can be used when passing the data to your custom field

Javascript/jQuery you can use .toLowerCase() on the field

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your response
But I can change case on submit because for the most part of user the case is correct. For some admin only, I need lower case.
I don't find any code to make this.
I think about a hook triggered after request on database and before displaying.